# Using both nginx-proxy in docker and nginx on host

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a docker-compose.yml which starts a service and uses [nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy) and [letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion). For SSL certificates challenge to pass, this setup must bind ports 80 and 443 to the host so Let's Encrypt can access it.

Is there any way this docker-compose setup can be used to serve a subdomain on a server which already has nginx+letsencrypt on the host?

Comment: Why not do the whole thing inside docker? Add letsencrypt/certbot inside the nginx container itself-- quicker deployments and if that node goes down, no one needs to configure SSL for it separately, no manual work required.

Comment: Yes, that would be the sane approach but the nginx from the host proxies for some old apps which are not yet "containerised".